# Convert number to datetime format using javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I convert **201604130630** this numbers to date time format in JavaScript.

I am using XML file and this data coming from XML. I want to convert into date format. Please help.

Comment: You split and concatenate into the format you'd like

Comment: how do you like it to be formatted? 
**2016/04/13 06:30** ?

Comment: i want  this 2016/04/13 06:30 format

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "201604130630";
var year = str.slice(0, 4);
var month = parseInt(str.slice(4, 6))-1;
var day = str.slice(6, 8);
var hour = str.slice(8, 10);
var minute = str.slice(10, 12);
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute)
alert(d);
```

Comment: Thank you ghazi2008..It worked for me.Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can create a date from the string by splitting the string

```
var input = '201604130630';
var year = input.slice(0, 4);
// Date object uses month 0 index based
var month = parseInt(input.slice(4, 6)) + 1;
var day = input.slice(6, 8);
var hour = input.slice(8, 10);
var minute = input.slice(10, 12);

var d = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute);
```

And then you can just concatenate the values or format it using `Date` methods:

- [getFullYear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear)
- [getMonth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)
- [getDate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate)
- [getHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours)
- [getMinutes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMinutes)
- [getSeconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getSeconds)

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = "201604130630";
var s = d.substring(0, 4) + '/' + d.substring(4, 6) + '/' + d.substring(6, 8) + ' ' + d.substring(8, 10) + ':' + d.substring(10, 12);
alert(s);
```